# jQuery in an Angular Controller: $(...).overhang is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, controller

So I'm attempting to implement [overhang.js](https://paulkr.github.io/overhang.js/) into my application because I like the alert messages it has.

Seemed like a fairly simple task at first... All I had to do (I thought) was replace the line in my controller,

```
alert("An HTTP request has been sent to the server.\nNow updating DaycareDB.db!");
```

with

```
$("body").overhang({
type: "success",
message: "An HTTP request has been sent to the server.\nNow updating DaycareDB.db!"
});
```

and that'd be that. Unfortunately when I attempt to execute the function and it reaches the `$("body".overhang({` line, nothing happens and the chrome console spits out "TypeError: jQuery(...).overhang is not a function" and then a bunch of other stuff.

How do I fix this?

Here is the full function:

```
$scope.RefreshDatabase = function() {
    $http.get('/RefreshDatabase')
    .then(function(response) {
        // alert("An HTTP request has been sent to the server.\nNow updating DaycareDB.db!");
        $("body").overhang({
        type: "success",
        message: "An HTTP request has been sent to the server.\nNow updating DaycareDB.db!"
        });
        // location.reload();
    });
```

I feel like I'm doing something silly or missing something that is causing my controller to not use the jquery properly.

EDIT:

This is how the head where all my angular and jquery and stuff is being included:

```
<head>
<title>Waiting List</title>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--Overhang.js-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./node_modules/overhang/dist/overhang.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="./node_modules/overhang/dist/overhang.min.js"></script>
<!--AngularJS-->
<script src="./angular/angular-1.5.8/angular-1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="./app.js"></script>
<script src="./Source/Client/Controllers/WaitingListController.js"></script>
<!--Font Awesome-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Other Files/(CSS Stuff) font-awesome-4.7.0/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--Foundation CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./Other Files/foundation-6.3.0-complete/css/foundation.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./Other Files/foundation-6.3.0-complete/css/app.css">
</head>
```

Also this is the full error message from the chrome console:

```
TypeError: $(...).overhang is not a function
at WaitingListController.js:13
at angular.js:16383
at m.$eval (angular.js:17682)
at m.$digest (angular.js:17495)
at m.$apply (angular.js:17790)
at l (angular.js:11831)
at J (angular.js:12033)
at XMLHttpRequest.t.onload (angular.js:11966)
```

Comment: @Xufox I updated the post

Comment: Why are you including the overhang css and js twice? Remove the first link tag and first script tag - they are unnecessary.

Comment: @trevor I;m not sure why that happened. Must've been a weird thing that happened while copying and pasting.

Comment: @trevor I just put the entire head in the file. I might be including jquery multiple times just because I'm using different packages... although that still doesn't tell me why the overhang function is causing the type error.

Comment: @Ryan: check my answer. You need move jquery up. I mean before Angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have included `Jquery` after `angularjs`.If so, than swap them. Remember to use `Jquery` in `Angularjs`, You need to include it before `Angularjs`.

Here is the correct hierarchy

```
    <script src="path/jquery"></script>
  <script src="path/overhang.js"></script>
    <script src="path/angular"></script>
```

Comment: Okay I moved it and changed the head in the post to reflect what's currently there. Now still trying to figure out what's causing the error message.

Comment: are you still getting same error? Can you test Jquery is properly loaded or not ?

Comment: yup moved it and getting the same error. Do I need to do something special in the controller file maybe? I've tried changing the statement from  `$("body").overhang({` to `jQuery("body").overhang({` but it produces roughly the same message just with the $ changed to the word jQuery in the message.

What the head looks like in the post right now is how it looks in the file. I've refreshed the page and everything too to make sure these changes were applied.

Comment: @rayn can you locally include Jquery rather than CDN link.? It mat=y than easier to debug?

Comment: I put these two lines in the head and it gave me the alert. So it seems jQuery is loading properly.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>`

`<script>$(function() { alert('hello') });</script>`

Comment: @Ryan I do not find any bug in this. As per docs everything seems good

Comment: sucks when this happens :( want me to link you to the github for it?